# How do I get keys to work with Chef's apt cookbook

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, chef-infra, apt

I'm running on 12.04 Ubuntu with Vagrant using Chef Solo.

The PPA repo: https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/postgresql-9.3
The apt coookbook: https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apt

Here's the concerning part from my recipe.

```
apt_repository 'postgresql-9.3' do
  uri          'http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/postgresql-9.3/ubuntu'
  distribution 'precise'
  components   ['main']
  keyserver    'keyserver.ubuntu.com'
  key          'D878D6C2'
  deb_src      true
end

execute 'apt-key-update' do
  command 'sudo apt-key update'
end

execute 'apt-update' do
  command 'sudo apt-get update --fix-missing'
end

package 'zsh' do
  action :install
end

package 'postgresql-9.3' do
  action :install
end
```

And here's the error:

```
==> default: [2014-07-02T15:23:52+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
==> default: [2014-07-02T15:23:52+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
==> default: [2014-07-02T15:23:52+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> default: [2014-07-02T15:23:52+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2014-07-02T15:23:52+00:00] ERROR: package[postgresql-9.3] (dotabay::default line 22) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '100'
==> default: ---- Begin output of apt-get -q -y install postgresql-9.3=9.3.3-1chl1~precise1 ----
==> default: STDOUT: Reading package lists...
==> default: Building dependency tree...
==> default: Reading state information...
==> default: The following extra packages will be installed:
==> default:   libpq5 postgresql-client-9.3 postgresql-client-common postgresql-common
==> default:   ssl-cert
==> default: Suggested packages:
==> default:   oidentd ident-server locales-all postgresql-doc-9.3 openssl-blacklist
==> default: The following NEW packages will be installed:
==> default:   libpq5 postgresql-9.3 postgresql-client-9.3 postgresql-client-common
==> default:   postgresql-common ssl-cert
==> default: 0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 167 not upgraded.
==> default: Need to get 4,804 kB of archives.
==> default: After this operation, 23.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
==> default: WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
==> default:   libpq5 postgresql-client-common postgresql-client-9.3 postgresql-common
==> default:   postgresql-9.3
==> default: STDERR: E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
==> default: ---- End output of apt-get -q -y install postgresql-9.3=9.3.3-1chl1~precise1 ----
==> default: Ran apt-get -q -y install postgresql-9.3=9.3.3-1chl1~precise1 returned 100
==> default: [2014-07-02T15:23:52+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest
  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = ["chef/cookbooks"]
    chef.add_recipe 'apt'
    chef.add_recipe 'dotabay'
  end
end
```

Comment: Why not just `include_recipe 'apt::default'` instead of manually updating things?

Comment: I have `chef.add_recipe 'apt'` in my Vagrantfile, doesn't this do that already? Anyways, after adding that to my recipe, it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Post your `Vagrantfile`. If you have that recipe, you don't need to execute apt-get update stuff

Comment: Okay, I've updated the post to include the Vagrantfile.

Comment: If you `vagrant ssh` into the instance and run `apt-get -q -y install postgresql-9.3=9.3.3-1chl1~precise1` what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/postgresql-9.3 you have the wrong signing key. It should be `C7917B12`.